# About Dell server's virtual terminal

Tags: java, security, server

(I haven't ssh password T_T)
When I try to start virtual terminal from Dell server panel ,The server give me a file:"viewer.jnlp...". I run this file by javaws.exe and it has some error:

> Unsigned applications requesting unrestricted access to the system
> The following resources have been signed using the weak signature algorithm MD5withRSA and are considered unsigned.

How I solve it?

Comment: You might be able to tweak the java.security file: https://java.com/en/configure_crypto.html#disableMD5

Comment: Others have hacked at the app - after all, the webstart stuff is just a delivery mechanism: https://gist.github.com/xbb/4fd651c2493ad9284dbcb827dc8886d6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I haven't experience this directly myself<sup>1</sup>, but I think you trying to use an old version of Dell's IDRAC firmware.  The problem will be that your version of IDRAC was designed to work with an old version of Java, and its JAR file is signed with MD5 signatures ... which recent versions consider to be insecure.

Your ideal solution will be to upgrade to a newer version of IDRAC.  If that's not practical, you need to get hold of a version of Java that is compatible.

Check the release notes for the version of IDRAC that you are using.

See also:  [idrac 6/7 console browser/java compatibility chart?](https://www.dell.com/community/Systems-Management-General/idrac-6-7-console-browser-java-compatibility-chart/td-p/4463953)

The other problem is going to be that IDRAC is relying on jnlp, and jnlp support was deprecated<sup>2</sup> in Java 9 and dropped in Java 11.  (But there is [OpenWebStart](https://openwebstart.com/).)

---

<sup>1 - ... but I have seen coworkers in "ops" struggling with this problem.

2 - Actually it is a bit more complicated than that.  Some [Oracle sources](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-deprecated-features.html) say that the launch technology was deprecated in Java 9, and [others](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-9205ABFD-2024-40C8-B01E-A7328BBE4276) still suggest Webstart as an alternative for Applets in Java 9.  But this is moot, since it **was** dropped in Java 11, and Java 9 is EOL.</sup>

Comment: JavaWebStart/JNLP was still supported in 9 and even [recommended over applet/plugin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-9205ABFD-2024-40C8-B01E-A7328BBE4276) (FWTW, especially as 9 is now way EOL) but was [dropped in _11_](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8185077)

Comment: Thanks!ur right!But I find another way: I can reset the password of root in the web page  IDRAC setting->network/security->user->root->next->change the password

Comment: OK ... so this question is borderline off-topic.  It would have been better to ask it on (probably) https://serverfault.com